# How to import large Term set CSV file?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, import, term-store

I am importing a csv file with 1 term set and approximately 12,000 terms. When I begin the import, it says something like "Please wait while we import your terms", and about 5 minutes later the popup windows says "Unable to display page". When I refresh the page my term set is missing approximately 2000 terms. According to Microsoft documentation I thought a term set can have a maximum of 30,000 terms so I am not sure what is going on? Is my request timing out?

The structure of my csv file is something like this, I changed names around for anonymity:

[image]

Specifically I am noticing after I refresh the page that the "IMP ID" (and all of its child terms) are not in my term set.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: are you using the sample file downloaded from SharePoint?http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/import-a-term-set-HA101818255.aspx

Comment: are you importing it from Central amdin or Powershell/

Comment: Yes I am using the sample file downloaded from SharePoint as my template, and I am importing it from Central admin

Comment: you can use PowerShell script to achieve this.  irrespective of large termset or small termset.

Answer (score 1):

In case you haven't already solved this issue, I found this post that explains how to import using CSOM PowerShell commands.

https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2014/11/29/importing-taxonomy-to-sharepoint-using-powershell/

While I'd like to provide more details, that WordPress post is far too lengthy and may completely miss the mark if you're looking for a GUI approach.

I'm experiencing the same issue (breaks at 2,000 terms) and will be trying a PowerShell approach.

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers. Instead include relevant details in your post so that it is not fuly dependent on a link that can break any day.

Answer (score 0):

If importing the term set through Central Admin is not working, try PowerShell.  An older SharePoint StackExchange post that provides a PowerShell script for importing term sets, [How to import term sets to Managed Metadata Service using PowerShell and CSV file](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20091/how-to-import-term-sets-to-managed-metadata-service-using-powershell-and-csv-fil), has a lot of positive feedback.

Additionally, double-check your CSV file and verify that:  1) there are no empty rows, and 2) the columns Level 1 Term – Level 4 Term have equal values throughout (e.g. “IMP ID” was not somehow entered as “IMPID.”)

Answer (score 0):

the below code is an answer to the same kind of question
    [ [How to import term sets to Managed Metadata Service using PowerShell and CSV file](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20091/how-to-import-term-)
      sets-to-managed-metadata-service-using-powershell-and-csv-fil] 
     and posted by 
        https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/4957/jorge-carvalho

```
Param([string]$CentralAdminURL, [string]$TermsCSV, [string]$ADGroup)
 cls
 # loading the term store
 $site = Get-SPSite -Identity($CentralAdminURL)
 $session = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession($site)
 $termstore = $session.TermStores[0]
  # Create a Taxonomy Group
 # I first create a Term Group
 $termGroup = "MY MM Group"
 $group = $termstore.CreateGroup($termGroup)
 $termstore.AddTermStoreAdministrator($ADGroup)
 $group.AddGroupManager($ADGroup)
 $termstore.CommitAll()
 # Import Taxonomy "Know How"
 # Create an instance of ImportManager
 $Importer = $termstore.GetImportManager()
 $varImported = ""
 $varMessages = ""
 $TermSetReader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($TermsCSV)

 # Syntax: ImportTermSet(TermGroup, TextReader, out isImported, out 
 errorMessage)
  $termset = $Importer.ImportTermSet($group ,$TermSetReader, ([REF] 
   $varImported), ([REF] $varMessages))
   $termset.set_Owner($ADGroup)
  $termset.TermStore.CommitAll()
  Write-Host $varMessages
  Write-Host $varImported
  $site.Dispose()
```