# Simple Powershell script to import TermSet file into Group

Tags: powershell, import, term-store, csv, term-set

I am looking for simple powerhell script to import termSet .csv file into TermGroup. What will be the simple script to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

There was a same question on stackexchange and answered.I hope this article helps you out.

[How to import term sets to Managed Metadata Service using PowerShell and CSV file](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20091/how-to-import-term-sets-to-managed-metadata-service-using-powershell-and-csv-fil)

Also the below TechNet article explains the CSV file format for metadata termset values.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424396.aspx

However if you have the well formatted CSV file, you can easily import it through Central Administration UI. Go to CA -> Managed Metadata Service -> Your TermGroup -> Right Click and import.